# How to write a python loop to change a value for a dictionary key in API request?

Tags: python, api, loops, python-requests

I am writing an API request that gives paginated results.
To get results from the next page I need to take a value of 'next_page_cursor' and put it in the parameters of my request that is a dictionary.

This is what I have tried so far. Need to keep changing **cursor** value in **params** until there are no more pages.

```
params = {'title': 'Cybertruck',
          'per_page':100,
          'cursor': '*'
         }


response = requests.get("https://api.aylien.com/news/stories", 
                       headers = headers,   params=params).json()

if "next_page_cursor" in response:
    cursor = response["next_page_cursor"]
```

Comment: You don't pass it explicitly as `'cursor': *` - that's invalid, what's your initial `params` dict?

Comment: The initial dict is what I have in the post, the default value for 'cursor' is * which I need to swap for 'next_page_cursor"

Comment: you can't have `*` explicitly as value - that will raise `SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`. Update your code

Comment: Thanks, updated. Forgot to use quote marks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop:

```py
params = {
    "title": "Cybertruck",
    "per_page": 100,
    "cursor": "initial_cursor"
}

def make_request(params)
    return requests.get("https://api.aylien.com/news/stories", 
                        headers=headers, params=params).json()
result = []
response = make_request(params)
while "next_page_cursor" in response:
    params["cursor"] = response["next_page_cursor"]
    response = make_request(params)
    result.append(response["information_your_are_interested_in"])
```

Comment: Thanks @nicoring! The resulting dictionary gives me only the values of the final page, rather than values from all pages. Do you know how to change that? Otherwise - this is very helpful, I'm much closer to what I was looking for

Comment: You have to accumulate the results somewhere. This depends on how the `response` looks like in this case. I will update the answer to give you some pointers how to do it.